I need to get long triple bar instead one
i'm working to develop backend in vscode and writing the following code but i need to get long triple bar instead one.
className={`${tab≡ "about" && "border-b border-solid border-primaryColor"               } py- px-5 mr-5 text-[16px] leading-7 text-headingColor font-semibold`} 

get long triple bar after tab

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask, including a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem where possible.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.
